# Programmatically getting list of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**EDIT:** This question is in a grey area between between SO and here. The source code isn't quite necessary, but I would at lease have a clue as to figure it out. Also, I've clarified and simplified my question. I will link my SO question here, and [here's a link to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290380/programmatically-getting-list-of-combinations).

**EDIT 2:** Check the bottom for some information on a potentially relevant formula.

**EDIT 3:** The main question is bolded for emphasis.

I'm trying to implement the `Math.hypot` function introduced in ECMAScript 6 in ECMAScript 5 for browsers, etc. that don't already support it (Firefox is the only one I've found that does), limiting overflow and underflow, and I ran into a massive dilemma: **how would I programmatically determine the list of all combinations of a given length of a single given set?** An example of this is all combinations of three elements out of four possible elements:

Here's what I need (in pseudocode):

```
Set: [a, b, c, d]
Number per combination: 3

What I need:
[[a, b, c],
 [a, b, d],
 [a, c, d],
 [b, c, d]]
```

Just in case it is relevant, I thought I would put the formula I'm trying to code. Only finding the set $C$ is the real stumbling block. The rest is rather easy to code. Refer to the Stack Overflow question for details of my current implementation so far.

Shorthand used in my formulation:

- $x$: the set of arguments passed to the function
- $x_i$: the argument passed at position $i$
- $n$: the total number of arguments
- $P_n=\prod_{i=1}^nx_i$
- $C$: the set of all combinations of $x$ excluding the last element and resulting set length $n-2$

  - Ex.: $x=\{a, b, c, d, e\}$
  - $C=\{{\{a, b, c\}}, {\{a, b, d\}}, {\{a, c, d\}}, {\{b, c, d\}}\}$
- $C_i$ the group/set element at index $i$
- $D_i$ the product of the elements at $C_i$

\begin{equation} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i}=\left|P_{n-1}\right|\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{{D_k}^2}+\left(\frac{x_n}{P_{n-1}}\right)^2} \end{equation}

Comment: You might want to consider splitting these question up. You seem to be asking five or six questions in the same post. Also, I would recommend you post this to [stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: First, I will clarify: the question is on how to find that set of all combinations. The second is a side question on just formulation, but I can live without knowing that.

Comment: I also fixed my question.

Comment: Maybe you want http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Enumerating_k-combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok a lot question let's answer the first!

Given a Set $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ all subsets with $n=3$ elements are:

$$ \{a,b,c\}, \{a,b,d\}, \{a,c,d\}, \{b,c,d\} $$

To generate this list you can use this (in c), given $|A|=\#A=m$

# Counter Array
    int count[n];
    int j;

```
# Initialise Array
for(; j < n; j++){
    count[j] = j;
}

# Now Iterate throught all combinations
while(1){
    for(j=n-1; 1; j--){
        count[j] += 1;

        if(count[j] >= m-n-j){
            if(j==0){
                goto abort;
            }
            count[j] = count[j-1]+1;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }

    # Here you got your Set `count`
}
abort:
```

But this is supposed to be a help to understand the problem. This can be optimized!

Comment: I fixed my question...I want the list of combination sets themselves. Counts will not help me at all unless it is used to find the combinations.

Comment: okay lets assume your set ${a,b,c,d}$ is ordered! then your first element is $a$ is equal to 0, the second $b$ to 1 and so on!
look at the `count` array it contains the indeces of you subset!

Comment: This got me started in the right direction already.

Answer (score 0):

To print all subsets of $S$ of length $m$, call $f(S, 0, 0, m)$, where $f$ is defined in pseudo-code as:

```
 function f(S, i, j, m)
 {
   if(i == n)
   {
      if(j == m)
         Print R

      return
   }

   f(S, i + 1, j, m)

   R[j] = S[i]
   f(S, i + 1, j + 1, m)
 }
```

and $R$ is a global array.

Comment: Would this be more optimal than the combination method in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/impinball/9476610) (assuming you're familiar with JavaScript)?

Comment: I'm not exactly familiar with javascript but that seems to be not efficient because getCombs is creating an array everytime it is called. I think the most efficient method is the one suggested on stackoverflow http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/67065/whats-your-favorite-bit-wise-technique/67087#67087